# Azure stream analytics query -incorrect results

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I've written 2 queries one after another in Azure stream analytics to push the data in dev and prod containers created in synapse environment.

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
  arrayElement_dev.ArrayValue.EventId as [id], 
  arrayElement_dev.ArrayValue.*, 
  d.EventProcessedUtcTime
INTO 
  [Dev-analytics]
FROM [EventHub-UAnalytics] d
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(d.Parameters) AS arrayElement_dev
WHERE d.AppId IN ('ba0ec8fb-8a48-42fe-b4e4-13635104b4b4'
,'fdf6faa4-4017-429a-8a3a-a7a31e5aa902')
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
  arrayElement_prod.ArrayValue.EventId as [id], 
  arrayElement_prod.ArrayValue.*, 
  e.EventProcessedUtcTime
INTO 
  [Prod-analytics]
FROM [EventHub-UAnalytics] e
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(e.Parameters) AS arrayElement_prod
WHERE e.AppId IN ('wwa0efb-8a48-42fe-b4e4-13635104b4b4'
,'azheoow4-4017-429a-8a3a-a7a31e5aa902')
```

Unfortunately my dev containers is getting production data but prod containers is giving the right results. I am unable to find out the cause of this data leakage in Dev container. I am new to Azure stream analytics.

Comment: Hi James, just to make sure, in query 2 the alias you have for the set returned by CROSS APPLY is `arrayElement_prod`, yet in the projection it's still `arrayElement_dev`. Can you double check your job doesn't have the same typo? Thanks

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for highlighting the issue in original question, I have updated it now

Comment: Hi James, is that one single job with 2 queries, or 2 different jobs? Also could you please share an input sample to compare the payload schema to your query?

Comment: Hey @Pakard, without some sample input data it's hard to know what's wrong here. By the way have you double checked your output configurations, for `Dev-analytics` and `Prod-analytics` - it may also be that both are targeting the same container.